# Windows: Remove the wallpaper using the command line

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

Is there a command to remove the desktop wallpaper and use a solid color?

Answer (score 1):

An often described way is to use

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "" /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

However, this doesn't work on Windows 7 (64bit?!) anymore; see this [Technet post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/02/05/how-can-i-hide-my-desktop-wallpaper.aspx).

A proposed solution is to use the [SetWallpaper](http://www.optimumx.com/downloads.html) tool. To remove the wallpaper run it in an elevated shell:

```
SetWallpaper /r
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this:
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  wallpaper_path /f

Hope this will help You